# Finding a selected expression

Tags: expression-manipulation, debugging

How can I find all expressions matching the one I am selecting?

This features exists in Matlab and is quite helpful:

[image]

Just trying to make my debugging easier.

Thanks!

Comment: An IDE will do this for you. I use VS Code with the Wolfram Language extension, and I get exactly the same behaviour you seek here.

Comment: Is this question about Mathematica? If yes, does standard "Menu/Edit/Find" help? Why not?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch that option is just not as user-friendly. I was hoping that the notebook would just have this feature...